# Next.js process.env is empty in production as image on a docker container

Tags: docker, next.js, deployment, environment-variables

I created an image with GitHub Actions of my Next.js app and everything works fine except for the environment variables that are only working when I am in local mode but not in production mode.

What I did for now is a `docker-image.yaml` workflow file for GitHub Actions:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    env:
      NODE_ENV: production
      NEXT_PUBLIC_API: http://example.com

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Build the Docker image
      run: docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag myapp:${{ github.run_number }}
    - name: Log in to Docker Hub
      uses: docker/login-action@v1
      with:
        username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
    - name: Push to Docker Hub
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
      with:
        context: .
        push: true
        tags: |
          aquarima/myapp:latest
        repository: aquarima/myapp:latest
```

I even set the same environment variable on the Dockerfile:

```
ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_API http://example.com
```

I run the container as `docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name myapp aquarima/myapp`

When I list the container variables they are both here but when I call `process.env` it is an empty object...